# Get unique ID of a test execution in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Does pytest generate a unique ID for each test execution? Theoretically, this execution ID should be same for all process of `pytest-xdist`.

The reason I am asking is that my main process in xdist doing a complex task for which the other process should wait. For waiting, I am creating a file. Once the file is deleted, other processes can start executing the test case. However, I want the file name to be random to avoid any conflicts. Possibly, `process-flag-<execution_id>`.

```
[pytest configure] -> Create a file 
                     [main process] -> Time taking task  -> remove file -> Start test case execution 
                                   [other process] -> wait for the file -> Start test case execution
```

**Edit:** Additionally, I am ingesting sample data for testing purpose which should be ingested in a unique bucket. For the same reason also I think execution ID should help

Comment: _my main process in xdist doing a complex task for which the other process should wait_ - or you could execute the complex task in custom `pytest_xdist_setupnodes` hookimpl and get all the waiting stuff for free.

Comment: @hoefling, I don't know about the hook. I checked in doc as well, it's not mentioned anywhere. Can you please share some reference if possible?

Comment: The complex task that I am talking about mainly ingests sample data for which the whole functionality should be tested. Therefore other nodes have to wait for the sample data to be ingested.

Answer (score 1):

> Does pytest generate a unique ID for each test execution? Theoretically, this execution ID should be same for all process of `pytest-xdist`.

`xdist` provides a `testrun_uid` fixture which returns a UUID formatted as the hex string:

```
def test_spam(testrun_uid):
    print("unique ID of the test run:", testrun_uid)
```

> The reason I am asking is that my main process in xdist doing a complex task for which the other process should wait.

Use the `pytest_xdist_setupnodes` hook for that. In your `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_xdist_setupnodes(config, specs):
    run_complex_task()
```

The task will be executed after the worker processes were spawned, but before any test starts.

Alternatively, you can also use vanilla `pytest`'s hooks, only check that you're in the master process. For example,

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    # slaveinput attribute is unset on master node, but available on worker nodes
    if not hasattr(config, 'slaveinput'):
        run_complex_task()
```

> I don't know about the hook. I checked in doc as well, it's not mentioned anywhere. Can you please share some reference if possible?

Unfortunately, `xdist` doesn't have an API reference, so best spot to read about the `xdist`-specific hooks is the code itself, i.e. the [`xdist.newhooks`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/blob/master/src/xdist/newhooks.py) module listing all the available hookspecs.